# What is the detail of python object creation process?

Tags: python, metaclass

When I learning the `__int__`, `__new__` , `__call__` and metaclasss of python,  I get confused about the following code:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        print 'enter MyMeta'
        super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, attr)
        print 'leave MyMeta'

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'enter MyMeta __call__'
        instance = super(MyMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'leave MyMeta __call__'
        return instance


class MyObj(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'enter MyObj __init__'
        super(MyObj, self).__init__()
        self.aaa = args[0]
        self.kw = kwargs
        print self.aaa, self.kw
        print 'leave MyObj __init__'

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'enter MyObj __new__'
        instance = super(MyObj, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        print 'leave MyObj __new__'
        return instance

obj = MyObj(123, k=456)
```

and output is:

```
enter MyMeta            #L1
leave MyMeta            #L2
enter MyMeta __call__   #L3
enter MyObj __new__     #L4
leave MyObj __new__     #L5
enter MyObj __init__    #L6
123 {'k': 456}          #L7
leave MyObj __init__    #L8
leave MyMeta __call__   #L9
```

My question is:

1,When an object is created, the process is `__call__` of metacall, and then  `__new__` and `__init__` of class,  Is is right?

This is what I can see from the log, is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) right - mostly - the `__call__` of the metaclass (in this case, the `__call__` of the superclass of your `metaclass` which is `type`) calls the `__init__` and `__new__` from the instance.

2) You throw way your kwargs to the instance's `__init__` and `__new__` by omitting passing then to the super `__call__` of the metaclass. The metaclass' `__call__` is responsible for invoking the instance's `__new__` and `__init__`.

On a side note: use Python 3 - there is no point in going deep learning how Python 2.x used to work by now - it is seven years since the last release of a Python 2, and 3 years up to its end of line. (Although the process you are investigating is not changed, but for the way the metaclass is declared - but what give me the "auf, this is old" is the `super` with parameters)

Comment: The OP had changed the code and question after I answered - the orignal question did not pass "kwargs" to `type.__call__`, and the question had a second part of "what happened to my kwargs"?

Comment: Thanks. The IDE I used suggest 'kwargs' is unexpected, So I delete it. I add kwargs and it works.

Comment: There is very much IDE's don't know about Python - doubly so when metaclasses are in play.